# Reading only date or only day time from JSON object

Tags: javascript, sql, jsonp

I have a  javascript code which reads data table from my server as JSON objects,apparently I am stuck at reading dateTime object(i.e dateTime variable in my database) ;

when I read it the output is as dd/mm/yyyy AM 12:00:00; I want to remove the AM 12:00:00 part from it,how can I do it?

also in my next requirement I only want to the day time i.e keep the AM 12:00 part and remove everything else....please help

Answer (score 0):

```
dt = "26/04/2012 AM 12:00;"
d= dt.replace(/ [AP]M \d\d:\d\d;/i,'')   // "26/04/2012"
t= dt.replace(/\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d /i,'') // "AM 12:00;"
```

Comment: The time i.e t seem to be working but date i.e d still displays the entire date i.e 26/04/2012 AM 12:00
also can u explain how .replace function works as I am now only copy pasting watever you have given

Comment: I have figured how the .replace works but still can't get it to replace AM 12:00:00

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the answer,I simply used substr i.e (26/04/2012 AM 12:00).substr(0,10)///output:26/04/2012...this was so stupid...and this format is accepted in javascript date variable:D